# How to scroll only the tabbarview and set tabbar as fixed in top using SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tabbar, singlechildscrollview

when I am not giving the height property in a container of tabBarView it is giving an error and when wrapping with `SingleChildScrollView` it is not scrollable and the bottom gets overflowed when input keyboard is raised. But, when I place `SingleChildScrollView` above the tabBar, it is working and both the tabBar and tabview is scrolling but I want only the tabBarView should be scrolled and not the bar

[image: my screenshot for bottom overflows]

My code

```
import 'package:copackd/screens/Shipment.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TrackingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TrackingPageState createState() => _TrackingPageState();
}

class _TrackingPageState extends State<TrackingPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(247, 68, 78, .9),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 80,),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Track Your Shipment",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 25,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                        flex: 8,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(247, 68, 78, .3),
                                  blurRadius: 20,
                                  offset: Offset(0,10)
                              )]
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),

                                child: TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: "Enter tracking id",
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                      border: InputBorder.none
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      new Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Container(

                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(247, 68, 78, .3),
                                    blurRadius: 20,
                                    offset: Offset(0,10)
                                )]
                            ),
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                              iconSize: 25,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              onPressed: () {},
                            )
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),

                ],

              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(60),topRight: Radius.circular(60))
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      DefaultTabController(
                        length: 2,
                        initialIndex: 0,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            TabBar(
                                indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
                                labelColor: Colors.black,
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                tabs: [Tab(text: "Sending"),Tab(text: "Receiving",)]
                            ),
                            SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    height: height * 0.5,
                                    child: TabBarView(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Sending(),
                                        Receiving(),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

add a you code ListView, it resolver you problem, example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
return ListView(
        Scaffold(
         body: Container(
```

i hope resolver you problem!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain what your code does otherwise the asker and probably other people won't learn anything from just copy & paste.